# Issue with Article Image Schema JSON-LD

Tags: seo, schema.org, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

Stack Overflow community

I have a website where I'm using JSON-LD scripts to include structured data. In one of the scripts, I'm specifying image URLs with the following format:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Article",
  "mainEntityOfPage": {
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "@id": "http://localhost/digitalclimbers/understand-laravel-with-features/"
  },
  "headline": "What Is Laravel",
  "image": [
    "http://localhost/digitalclimbers/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/Untitled-design-4-min-300x300.jpg",
    "http://localhost/digitalclimbers/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/Untitled-design-4-min-480x360.jpg",
    "http://localhost/digitalclimbers/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/Untitled-design-4-min-1200x840.jpg"
  ],
  "description": "Understand what is Laravel Framework, and its key features",
  "datePublished": "2023-03-29T21:29:59+05:30",
  "dateModified": "2024-01-26T09:43:41+05:30",
  "wordCount": 256,
  "about": ["Definition", "Laravel"],
  "articleSection": "Laravel",
  "inLanguage": "en-IN",
  "author": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "Md Taufique Khan",
    "image": {
      "@type": "ImageObject",
      "url": "http://localhost/digitalclimbers/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/Untitled-design-5.jpg",
      "width": 150,
      "height": 150,
      "caption": "author alttag"
    },
    "url": "https://example.com/author/john-doe",
    "sameAs": [
      "https://lookmyweb.com",
      "https://google.com",
      "https://facebook.com"
    ]
  },
  "publisher": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "Digital Climber",
    "logo": {
      "@type": "ImageObject",
      "url": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\digitalclimbers/wp-content/themes/tk/assets/Images/Logo/publisher-logo.webp",
      "width": 492,
      "height": 150,
      "caption": "Logo of Digital Climber - A Reliable Source for Learning Digital Marketing & Web Development"
    },
    "url": "http://localhost/digitalclimbers",
    "sameAs": [
      "link1",
      "link2",
      "link3"
    ]
  }
}
</script>
```

but according to Google, the image URL is invalid

```
"image": [
    "http://localhost/digitalclimbers/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/Untitled-design-4-min-300x300.jpg",
    "http://localhost/digitalclimbers/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/Untitled-design-4-min-480x360.jpg",
    "http://localhost/digitalclimbers/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/Untitled-design-4-min-1200x840.jpg"
  ],
```

Here is the [Google Report](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results/result?id=2fHGaw_g8pl6EdhuXMNwzg)

Help me to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your general markup is correct, but `localhost` is a reserved host, that is not accessible outside of the scope of your local computer. This is most likely why Google reports it as an invalid URL. If you replace localhost with e.g. example.com your markup will validate just fine.

In addition, you might want to specify the image as ImageObject, so you can also add meta information like caption and creation date:

This is ideal structure

```
"image": [
    {
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "url": "https://example.com/image1.jpg",
            "contentUrl": "https://example.com/image1.jpg",
            "caption": "Caption of image 1",
            "dateCreated": "2018-12-06"
    },
    {
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "url": "https://example.com/image2.jpg",
            "contentUrl": "https://example.com/image2.jpg",
            "caption": "Caption of image 2",
            "dateCreated": "2018-12-07"
    },
]
```

But this is also correct

```
"image": [
    "https://example.com/image2.jpg",
    "https://example.com/image2.jpg",
    "https://example.com/image2.jpg"
  ],
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable reply, I go with your code, but please check the schema Google doc "image" part, according to this my schema is valid. Have you any idea what is going on

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/article

Comment: I just revised my answer... Please have a look.

Comment: Now I understand that both my schema and yours are correct because the URL comes from localhost; that's why Google shows an error. I've added a comment for anyone who may face the same issue in the future.

Thanks a lot, @tobias-schwarz